# Why are there 8 bytes between the end of a buffer and the saved frame pointer?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, stack-overflow

I am doing a stack-smashing exercise for coursework, and I have already completed the assignment, but there is one aspect that I do not understand.

Here is the target program:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                            
#include <string.h>                                            

int bar(char *arg, char *out)                                  
{                                                              
  strcpy(out, arg);                                            
  return 0;                                                    
}                                                              

void foo(char *argv[])                                         
{                                                              
  char buf[256];                                               
  bar(argv[1], buf);                                           
}                                                              

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                               
{                                                              
  if (argc != 2)                                               
    {                                                          
      fprintf(stderr, "target1: argc != 2\n");                 
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                      
    }                                                          
  foo(argv);                                                   
  return 0;                                                    
}
```

Here are the commands used to compile it, on an `x86` virtual machine running `Ubuntu 12.04`, with `ASLR` disabled.

```
gcc -ggdb -m32 -g -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector  -m32  target1.c   -o target1
execstack -s target1
```

When I look at the memory of this program on the stack, I see that `buf` has the address `0xbffffc40`. Moreover, the saved frame pointer is stored at `0xbffffd48`, and the return address is stored at `0xbffffd4c`.

These specific addresses are not relevant, but I observe that even though `buf` only has length `256`, the distance `0xbffffd48 - 0xbffffc40 = 264`. Symbolically, this computation is `$fp - buf`.

**Why are there `8` extra bytes between the end of `buf` and the stored frame pointer on the stack?**

Here is some disassembly of the function `foo`. I have already examined it, but I did not see any obvious usage of that memory region, unless it was implicit (ie a side effect of some instruction).

```
   0x080484ab <+0>:     push   %ebp                    
   0x080484ac <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp               
   0x080484ae <+3>:     sub    $0x118,%esp             
   0x080484b4 <+9>:     mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax          
   0x080484b7 <+12>:    add    $0x4,%eax               
   0x080484ba <+15>:    mov    (%eax),%eax             
   0x080484bc <+17>:    lea    -0x108(%ebp),%edx       
   0x080484c2 <+23>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)          
   0x080484c6 <+27>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)             
   0x080484c9 <+30>:    call   0x804848c <bar>         
   0x080484ce <+35>:    leave                          
   0x080484cf <+36>:    ret
```

Comment: Because frames are usually aligned to 16 (or perhaps 8, I forgot the details) bytes.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, The address `0xbffffc40` is already aligned to 16 bytes, and 256 is certainly a multiple 16.

Comment: Is that area being used to store registers?

Comment: 'buf' doesn't contain an address. It *has* an address.

Comment: @EJP, That was poor terminology on my part, but I am trying to understand your second point.

Comment: Exception handler frame?

Comment: @MantoshKumar, Note the compiler flag `-fno-stack-protector`.

Answer (score 3):

Basile Starynkevitch gets the prize for mentioning `alignment`.

It turns out that `gcc 4.7.2` defaults to aligning the frame boundary to a 4-word boundary. On 32-bit emulated hardware, that is 16 bytes. Since the saved frame pointer and the saved instruction pointer together only take up 8 bytes, the compiler put in another 8 bytes after the end of `buf` to align the top of the stack frame to a 16 byte boundary.

Using the following additional compiler flag, the 8 bytes disappears, because the 8 bytes is enough to align to a 2-word boundary.

```
-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2
```